# Matlab to Python, Plotting problem, possible bad observation?

Tags: python, plot

I have a spectrum that I currently have 25 observations for. There are 29 orders in each spectrum (rows) and 1973 pixels (columns), (Originally 2047 because I have removed bad observations and trimmed to remove outliers.   Ive applied a Barycentric correction (see code) and I want to plot the wavelength (Tw) against the Intensity (Tint) and identify one order and overlay 25 of the observations.  Most of the observations are overlaying but Im getting an odd, background plot (see image). Im really stuck as to what has happened.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72wDk.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
import scipy.io as sio
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# Corrected the number of pixels
num_pixels = 1973

# Corrected the number of orders
num_orders = 29

# Load data from the "Prepared.mat" file
prepared_mat_file_path = '/Users/xxx/Desktop/Star/Prepared.mat'
data = sio.loadmat(prepared_mat_file_path)

# Specify the path to the HDF5 file
hdf5_file_path = '/Users/xxx/Desktop/Star/bcorr_fib4_all.mat'

# Open the HDF5 file for reading
with h5py.File(hdf5_file_path, 'r') as hdf5_file:
    # Access the dataset you want
    bcorr_fib4_all = hdf5_file['bcorr_fib4_all'][:]

# Access the data from "Prepared.mat"
# Trim the data to 1973 pixels
ALLfib4spec = data['ALLfib4spec'][:, :num_pixels, :]
nALLfib4specbNc = data['nALLfib4specbNc'][:, :num_pixels, :]
ALLfib4specwave = data['ALLfib4specwave'][:, :num_pixels, :]

# Generate some example data (replace with your actual data)
# Note: You should replace this random data with your actual data.
wave = np.random.rand(num_orders, num_pixels)
bcorr_fib4_all = np.random.rand(num_observations)


# Barycentric correction
# Note: Ensure that the barycentric correction is being applied correctly.

# Initialize ALLwv with the appropriate dimensions
ALLwv = np.zeros((num_orders, num_pixels, num_observations))

for s in range(ALLfib4spec.shape[2]):
    tWVout = ALLfib4specwave[:, :, s]
    for ord in range(tWVout.shape[0]):
        tWVout[ord, :] = shift_vel(tWVout[ord, :], bcorr_fib4_all[s] * -1)
    # dimensions are: [orders pixels observations]
    ALLwv[0:tWVout.shape[0], :, s] = tWVout  # Assign values to the corresponding orders in ALLwv

# Create the log step wavelength axis so each pixel is the same velocity size
c = 299792458
logstep = 1e-6
a = 8
velstep = (np.exp(a + logstep) - np.exp(a)) / np.exp(a) * c
lw = np.arange(np.log(min(Tw[:, 1]) + 2), np.log(max(Tw[:, 1]) - 2), logstep)

# Define the order you want to plot (e.g., order 16)
order_to_plot = 16

# Extract wavelengths for the chosen order
Tw = np.transpose(ALLwv[order_to_plot, :, :])
Tint = np.transpose(nALLfib4specbNc[order_to_plot, :, :])

# Number of observations
num_observations = Tint.shape[0]

# Create a plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

# Loop through observations and plot each one
for observation_index in range(num_observations):
    wavelengths = Tw[observation_index, :]
    intensities = Tint[observation_index, :]

    # Plot the observation
    plt.plot(wavelengths, intensities, label=f'Observation {observation_index + 1}')

# Add labels and title
plt.xlabel('Wavelength')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.title(f'Wavelength vs. Intensity for Order {order_to_plot}')
plt.legend()  # Add a legend to distinguish observations
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Without the actual data it'll be hard to identify the root cause of this. It looks like Tw[i] and Tint[i] at i = 3, 13 or 23 are just "bad". Presumably because ALLfib4specwave and nALLfib4specbNc are "bad" at these indices. Hard to tell without the data.

Comment: what can I post here to assist?

Comment: Are you able to [edit] your question to include the data that generates that image and create a [mre]? See [ask] for more details.